# Optimizing the Buefy table component for large datasets

Tags: vue.js, optimization, buefy

I'm working on a Vue.js application that shows a big dataset using the Buefy table component. The table functions okay with small amounts of data, but as the data gets larger, it begins to lag and become unresponsive. I've heard that the vue-virtual-scroll library can increase performance. However, I'm not sure how to integrate it with Buefy tables.
How can I integrate vue-virtual-scroll with Buefy tables?

Any guidance, code examples, or resources to help me get started with optimizing buefy table component would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a Virtualized Table that loads rows when user scrolls. so initial load will be at its minimum.

checkout these two awesome tables:
[surelyTable](https://www.surely.cool/) & [vxeTable](https://vxetable.cn/).

see how virtualization works & implent it in your own table.
or just use one of these tables.